# How to pass convert expression in parameter using c#?

Tags: c#, t-sql

I had an adhoc insert statement created in c# code using string builder.

```
var str = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
str.Append(" INSERT INTO Table_01 ( ID,");
        str.Append("Comment,");
        str.Append("DateTimeStamp,");
str.Append(" ) VALUES( ");
        str.Append("'" + Guid.NewGuid() + "',");
        str.Append("'" + CaseComment + "',");
        str.Append("CONVERT(DATETIME, '" + DateTime.Now.Year + "/" + DateTime.Now.Month + "/" + DateTime.Now.Day + "',120)");
```

I have converted this code to SqlParameter:-

```
var str = INSERT INTO Table_01(ID,Comment,DateTimeStamp)     
VALUES(@ID,@Comment,@DateTimeStamp)
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con))
{
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", Guid.NewGuid()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Comment", CaseComment));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateTimeStamp", ?????));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Before passing DateTime, I have to make sure that format is equal to "**convert(varchar, getdate(), 120) -- 2016-10-23 06:10:55(24h)**" as in TSQL. 
How will i pass @datetime parameter using TSQL Convert expression?

Comment: when you assign the value to `@datetimestamp` why not convert it at that point to a datetime? then the conversion will be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Convert` class. Try something like this,

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateTimeStamp", Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now)));
```

or

```
cmdItemSearch.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)); 
cmdItemSearch.Parameters["@EndDate"].Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Date format should always be yyyy-mm-dd. Equal to TSQL = convert(varchar, getdate(), 120) -- 2016-10-23 06:10:55(24h)

Comment: `sqlcommand` automatically handles it for you as long as the data type is `datetime`

Comment: what is the data type of `DateTimeStamp` in your table?

Comment: then do I need to use Convert.ToDateTime()?

Comment: DateTimeStamp datatype is DateTime

Comment: what is the datatype of the variable you are passing to the parameter?

Comment: I need current DateTime so using DateTime.Now to pass into the paramter

Comment: if you pass `DateTime.Now`, then no need to use the `Convert` class. pass `DateTime.Now` directly to the parameter

Comment: just like this, `cmdItemSearch.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
cmdItemSearch.Parameters["@EndDate"].Value = DateTime.Now;`

Answer (score 1):

Why not using [String Format for DateTime](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the database column is actually a `DateTime` and not `varchar` you don't need to convert on insert if using a parameter.  Databases don't save dates as strings, but as offsets, and the only reason you had to convert it when using your inline SQL was because you had to make sure the DB recognized the string as a `DateTime` so it could internally convert it back correctly.   This is avoided using parameters.

(In other words, just insert `DateTime.Now`, don't rip it apart into a string)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, whenever I need to insert the current date/time stamp to a table, I like to use the server date as opposed to the client date. If the app is running on the same box as SQL server then it doesn't matter, but if the app is running on a different box then it's better to have consistent dates from the same timezone. So I would remove the datetime parameter altogether and use the SQL date function GetDate() as follow:

```
var str = INSERT INTO Table_01(ID,Comment,DateTimeStamp)     
VALUES(@ID,@Comment,GetDate())
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con))
{
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", Guid.NewGuid()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Comment", CaseComment));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```